# Get a text pattern between the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

This is the HTML text

```html
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlyear" class="page-heading" style="background-color: rgb(255, 244, 244); width: 95px; outline: 1px solid blue;">   
<option selected="selected" value="Select Year">Select Year</option> <option value="2000">2000</option>    
<option value="2001">2001</option>    
<option value="2002">2002</option>    
<option value="2003">2003</option>    
<option value="2004">2004</option>    
<option value="2005">2005</option>    
<option value="2006">2006</option>    
<option value="2007">2007</option>    
<option value="2008">2008</option>    
<option value="2009">2009</option>    
<option value="2010">2010</option>    
<option value="2011">2011</option>    
<option value="2012">2012</option>    
<option value="2013">2013</option>    
<option value="2014">2014</option>    
<option value="2015">2015</option>    
<option value="2016">2016</option>    
<option value="2017">2017</option>    
</select>
```

From this I'm trying to extract the years like **frm 2000 till 2017**, so for this I'm first doing a regex pattern match between string "" and then getting all the numbers from it but my regex is getting wrong.

```
var regex = /<option selected(.*)</option>/;
var newtext = \"{{text}}\".replace(regex,'')
```

The first step to get the years is itself getting failed.
Any suggestion where it is getting wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Please format your html with proper new lines to improve the chances of this question being read by more people.

Comment: You should not parse HTML with REGEX. Use XML parser for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's way more easier by directly querying the `select` element and grabbing its `option` values than messing with plain HTML:

```js
var yearsArray = [];

var options = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlyear').options;

// i = 1, because we don't want the option[0], which is "Select Year"
for(var i = 1; i < options.length; i++) {
 yearsArray.push(options[i].value);
}

console.log(yearsArray);
```

```html
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlyear\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlyear" class="page-heading" style="background-color: rgb(255, 244, 244); width: 95px; outline: 1px solid blue;">
  <option selected="selected" value="Select Year">Select Year</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
</select>
```

Comment: oh its great...it worked very well..Thank you for the time and effort